# dropdown is not working in this code

Tags: angularjs

First two lines are from js file where value is fetching through id.

```js
var activity = document.getElementById("bactivity").value;
        var activity1 = activity.options[activity.selectedIndex].value;
```

```html
<select style="font-size:15px" ng-model="activity" value="Enter activity" id="bactivity">
            <option selected>select</option>
            <option value="Fitness">Fitness</option>
            <option value="Aerobics">Aerobics</option>
            <option value="Dance">Dance</option>
            <option value="Martial arts">Martial arts</option>
            <option value="Boxing">Boxing</option>
            <option value="Athletics">Athletics</option>
        </select>
```

the above code is from html file where I am displaying data in form of dropdown and when I am selecting any value it generate error that option is invalid. Some tell what was my mistake there so I can make it correct.

Comment: Try changing the line `var activity = document.getElementById("bactivity").value;` to `var activity = document.getElementById("bactivity");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Herre you can find the working code, you just had to take the elements not their value (first 2 lines of code):

```js
var activity = document.getElementById("bactivity");
        var activity1 = activity.options[activity.selectedIndex];
```

```html
<select style="font-size:15px" ng-model="activity" value="Enter activity" id="bactivity">
            <option selected>select</option>
            <option value="Fitness">Fitness</option>
            <option value="Aerobics">Aerobics</option>
            <option value="Dance">Dance</option>
            <option value="Martial arts">Martial arts</option>
            <option value="Boxing">Boxing</option>
            <option value="Athletics">Athletics</option>
        </select>
```